# update query remove quotes from query in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

i am using codeigniter with postgresql database 
i want to set Default value if we can't get value or value == '' from $_POST or $this->input->post() then need to set value DEFAULT but whenever codeigniter execute query its append a quote like "DEFAULT" but i want my query like below example

Example:

```
Current Output :

update tablename set fieldname = 'DEFAULT' where 


Required Output :

update tablename set fieldname = DEFAULT  where condition
```

here problem with codeigniter query which append quotes for DEFAULT value whenever i will update 
please help me to remove quotes from core file  whenever i will execute query in database through codeigniter

Comment: where is your query? Please post here that too.

Comment: @Nil'z i want to do it for global i mean for my whole application so just simple query problem is not in query but problem in codeigniter core library which is using for database that's create a problem added quotes('DEFAULT') instead of DEFAULT so just if possbile then please suggest me

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @Deniel because in our custom function doesn't allow blank value for integer datatype, so i just think if i will specify globally then its working fine

Answer (score 1):

This is a valid question. First, in postgres for example there are constants such as `CURRENT_DATE` and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` or in MySQL `NOW()` that, if quoted will cause an error. The way I handle these case is by using the code igniighter `set` function with a third parameter set to False to tell code ignighter to False like so:

```
    $this->db->where('id',999);
    $this->db->set('draft', False);
    $this->db->set('submission_date', 'CURRENT_DATE', False);
    $this->db->set('status','ok');
    $this->db->update('projects');
```

This will produce the following query:

```
UPDATE projects SET draft=False, submission_date=CURRENT_DATE, status='ok' WHERE id='999';
```

Reference: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#inserting-data